# Android FragmentStatePagerAdapter Preload Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

3 fragments will displayed on ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

I named those fragments and 3 fragments have customed layout

> 1.StepOneFragmet
>
> 2.StepTwoFragmet
>
> 3.StepThreeFragmet

I need to fetch the data from Server and binding those data into different fragment separately.  How can i create and initialized 3 fragments when i loaded the viewpager?

If i access StepThreeFragment, it will return NullpointerException. It means that the system haven't create and initialize the Fragment.

There are my codes:

Activity:

```
mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
mFragments.add(new StepOneFragment());
mFragments.add(new StepTwoFragment());
mFragments.add(new StepThreeFragment());

mPagerAdapter = new StepPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),mFragments);
mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

StepThreeFragment f = (StepThreeFragment)((StepPagerAdapter) mPager.getAdapter()).getmFragments().get(2);
f.textView_profile.setText("1111");//--->NullPointerException
```

StepPagerAdapter:[Code](https://codeshare.io/TXRuL)

```
public ArrayList<Fragment> getmFragments(){
    return mFragments;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position);
}
```

StepThreeFragment: (For example -> setText of TextView)

[Code](https://codeshare.io/NNwab)

Comment: Not enough code post more

Comment: @Haroon for testing those 3 fragments are the same layout with single TextView. I want to set the Text on third fragment after load the viewpager. So that is all code what i posted

Comment: Initialisation of the fragment didn't even had to be finished before loading was completed.
You should set the adapter after loading. Set arguments to those fragments and then pass them to pager.

Comment: @LubosHoracek i got your idea! It means that i need to pass all the data by using newInstance and set arguments when i received the data from Server. Like that :https://codeshare.io/INKea  it works.

Comment: Maybe the faster way to set a lot of data is declare all the arrayList/var in activity and declare as public static. Those fragments will access some data from activity directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity:

```
//assign MyObject some valu form your web services

mPagerAdapter = new StepPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
mPager.addFragments(MyObject obj);
```

StepOneFragment.java

```
    public static final StepOneFragment newInstance( MyObject obj ){

    StepOneFragment f = new StepOneFragment();

    // Get arguments passed in, if any
    Bundle args = f.getArguments();
    if (args == null) {
        args = new Bundle();
    }

    // Add parameters to the argument bundle
    args.putParcelable("obj", obj );          // clone or referenced?

    MyObject implements parcelable
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;

    }

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyObject object = getArguments().getParcelable("obj");

     }
```

Fragmentstatepageradapter:

```
public fraf extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList();

    public fraf(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
         super(fragmentManager);
    }

    public void addFragments(Myobject obj){

        fragments.add(StepOneFragment.newInstance(obj));
        fragments.add(StepTwoFragment.newInstance(obj));
        fragments.add(StepThreeFragment.newInstance(obj));
        notifydatasetchanged();

     }

     @Override
     public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
     }

     @Override
     public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer is works! I need to pass data by using argument and Bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StepThreeFragment f = (StepThreeFragment)((StepPagerAdapter) mPager.getAdapter()).getItem(2);
f.textView_profile.setText("1111");
```

Comment: cannot write on this. I tried. The view of fragment is not created. It will show the nullpointerexception